# Run kubernetes from source and configure cloud provider

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to run kubernetes from source (./hack/local-up-cluster.sh) and still properly configure the cloud provider from this type of setup?  For example, if an instance is running on AWS EC2 and all prerequisites are met including proper exports, aws cli and configs but keep getting an error stating that the cloud provider was not found.  KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws, Zone is set to us-west-2a, etc...

`Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. plugin.host.GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `hack/local-up-cluster.sh` is designed to be run on a cloud provider. However, `cluster/kube-up.sh` *is* designed to work when building from source:

```
$ make release
$ export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws
$ cluster/kube-up.sh  # Uses the release built in step 1
```

There are lots of options which can be configured, and you can find more details [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/) (just ignore the part about https://get.k8s.io).

Comment: For the `hack/local-up-cluster.sh` script, variable has name `CLOUD_PROVIDER`